# How count max of a group?

Tags: php, mysql

I need a command that would pick out the most count of positive issues from an author, for example, the result should look like this:

```
Author     WithTheMostMax
Author1                2
```

AUTHOR TABLE

```
AuthorID    AuthorName
Author1    AuthorName1
Author2    AuthorName2
Author3    AuthorName3
```

ISSUES LIST

```
AuthorID    Issues
Author1          1
Author2          0
Author3          0
Author1          1
```

Comment: Where is your TRIED query ?

Comment: use `group by` and `count` in mysql.

Comment: In your question you write you want the count of positive issues from an author, this can be done with count. `SUM` can be used here but only if you want to add all issues per author. `COUNT` will provide the amount of times an author has a positive value in issues field. These results can differ.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT AuthorName, SUM(Issues) AS WithTheMostMax FROM issues_list INNER JOIN issues_list.AuthorID = author_table.AuthorID
GROUP BY AuthorName ORDER BY SUM(Issues) DESC
```

Comment: I think you are missing the limit part:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `count()` if 1 issue per author is stored in each row in issues table.

```
SELECT `authors`.`authorID`, COUNT(`issues`) as `maxIssues`
FROM `issues_list` INNER JOIN `authors` ON   
`issues_list`.`authorID`=`authors`.`authorID`
WHERE `issues`>0
GROUP BY `issues_list`.`authorID`
ORDER BY `maxIssues` DESC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bbb79/2